# Creating c3 graphs with dynamic values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, c3.js

Below is the code I'm using to generate a line graph using c3.js. In the variable 'value' I'll get the values to be plotted as comma separated values. I've hard coded the values now. With this code, the graph generated has only one value - '0'.

This code doesn't work :

```
       var name = "Graph Values";
        var value = "120,150,120,120,120";
          var obj = { 
           "data1": [value]
            }
          var chart = c3.generate({
              bindto: '#chart1',
              data: {
                columns: [
                 [name].concat(obj.data1)
                ]
              }
          });
```

This code works :

```
       var name = "Graph Values";
        var value = "120,150,120,120,120";
          var obj = { 
           "data1": [120,150,120,120,120]
            }
          var chart = c3.generate({
              bindto: '#chart1',
              data: {
                columns: [
                 [name].concat(obj.data1)
                ]
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the value you declared was not in the proper way Try this

```
 var value = [120,150,120,120,120];
  var obj = { 
       "data1": value
        } ;
```

Comment: This works. But my value won't be hard coded like this. What if from jquery I'm getting 

var value = "120,150,120,120,120"; 

How will I change it into the other format, with square brackets?

Comment: Oh, Its an array. will try that.

Comment: var obj = { 
           "data1": [value]
            }
this would return an array like this 
data1[0]=>"120,150,120,120,120"

Answer (score 0):

you can put your data in an array.

```
var Array=[]; //Store your dynamic values here 
var chart = c3.generate({
              bindto: '#chart1',
              data: {

                            columns:[Array],
                             type : 'bar',


                    }
      });
```